# Field values rendered null when using HTTP GET call in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0

This is domain class of Person :

```
 package com.sample
 class Person {
    String id
    String name
    Integer age
    Address address
static hasMany = [pets:Pet, alias: String, aliases : Alias]

static mapWith = "mongo"
 static constraints = {
      address nullable:true
      pets nullable :true
 }
}
```

This is the domain class of Address :

```
 package com.sample

 class Address {

   String address
   static mapWith = "mongo"
   static constraints = {
           address maxSize: 1000
   }
 }
```

This is ShowPerson method in PersonController:

```
 def showPerson(String name,String age){

            if(Person.findByAgeAndName(age,name) != null) {
                    render Person.findByAgeAndName(age,name) as JSON
            }
            else {

                def addobj = new Address(address: "kondapur")
                addobj.save(flush:true)

                def pet1 = new Pet(name : "Dog", breed : "A")
                pet1.save(flush:true)

                def alias1 = "ALIAS1"
                def alias2 = "ALIAS2"

                def list = ["A"]
                def aliases1 = new Alias(aliasname : [list])
                aliases1.save(flush:true)

                def person = new Person(name : name, age : age,  address : addobj, pets : [pet1], alias : [alias1, alias2], aliases : [aliases1])

                person.save()   

                render person as JSON
            }

        }
```

Initially there are no persons in DB(which impliesPerson.findByAgeAndName(age,name) == null) Hence it creates a new object and saves it in database). So when I click on the url

```
 > http://localhost:8080/TestJson/showPerson/sample/23
```

The output now is :

[image: name field of address is seen]

Now when I reclick on the same url (implies Person.findByAgeAndName(age,name) != null) Hence it gets from the database):

The output now is :

[image: name field of address became null]

In database the address is saved as :

[image: saved correctly]

In database the person is saved as :

[image: The id of the address is stored]

Can someone tell me how can I get the address (encircled in red) as not null and get the corresponding value when I try to get a saved object from database (i.e in this case kondapur and not null)

Comment: good question detailing +1

Comment: I don't see a `name` field in `Address`.

Comment: "String address" in domain class Address is what Iam referring to

Answer (score -1):

Grails JSON marshaller by default doesn't add nested classes, you have to add one line of code:

```
     def showPerson(String name,String age){

   JSON.use('deep')// <============================== Add this line

                if(Person.findByAgeAndName(age,name) != null) {
                        render Person.findByAgeAndName(age,name) as JSON
                }
            else {

                def addobj = new Address(address: "kondapur")
                addobj.save(flush:true)

                def pet1 = new Pet(name : "Dog", breed : "A")
                pet1.save(flush:true)

                def alias1 = "ALIAS1"
                def alias2 = "ALIAS2"

                def list = ["A"]
                def aliases1 = new Alias(aliasname : [list])
                aliases1.save(flush:true)

                def person = new Person(name : name, age : age,  address : addobj, pets : [pet1], alias : [alias1, alias2], aliases : [aliases1])

                person.save()   



                render person as JSON
            }

        }
```

Comment: Even adding that Im getting name field of address as null.Is it because the address table is not getting linked to person table via a foreign key  ?

Comment: You're getting the address id, so Person has the address reference, BUT address has not a Person reference if you delete Person, address will continue existing (and you'll have a useless information in the DB ), but that is another problem.

Comment: Iam getting address id but why Iam I not getting address name? If person has the address reference Why is the address not showing as null when I delete that particular address in address table?

Comment: If you want a bidirectional references you should add:  
static belongsTo = [person: Person]  in your Address domain class.

Comment: The object in your controller has the address reference (it's lazy loaded but if you try to get it, you will) when that java(groovy) object  is converted to json, the json representation will not contain the address object.

Comment: Im new to grails so Can you please tell me how I can get the name of address field?

Comment: did you add JSON.use('deep') before render as JSON?

Comment: BTW, the address: null in your JSON is not referring to  the address field, is referring to the address object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54600/discussion-between-user2613399-and-luiszavaleta).